# Displaying a dropdown that contains hierarchial data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display hierarchial categories in a drop down list.

**Each child category should be indented slightly.**

My model looks like:

```
Category
  id
  parent_id
  name
  timestamps
```

I already have a method that loads all the categories.

```
categories = ...
```

I believe I will have to somehow do this with recursion.

I also have a hash which I created by looping through the categories, this way I can easily fetch a category by it's id.

```
map = {}

categories.each do |c|
  map[c.id] = c
end
```

Now I need help on how to recursively build a select/dropdown statement and indenting the child categories.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your class will be something like this

```
class Category < Struct.new(:id, :name, :parent_id)
end
```

The function which prints your drop down list out

```
def print_child(categories, parent_id, html = '', symbol = '=')
  categories.each do |category|
    if category.parent_id == parent_id
      node_html = "<option>#{ symbol } #{ category.name }<option>"
      html += print_child(categories, category.id, node_html, symbol + symbol)
    end
  end
  html
end
```

I will simply create an array of categories

```
categories = [
  Category.new(1, 'A', 0),
  Category.new(2, 'B', 1),
  Category.new(3, 'C', 2),
  Category.new(4, 'D', 2),
  Category.new(5, 'E', 1),
]
```

Print the result

```
html = print_child(categories, 0)
p html
```

Comment: I'm not really looking for a gem for this, I want learn how to do it manually as I can see this being a beneficial thing to understand.